# Google Analytics reporting API does not return all data

Tags: python-3.x, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-api-python-client

I would like to get some statistics of all products on a weekly basis. However, the data of the product in some weeks does not return. I am using the code(with pagination) below.

```
VIEW_ID='xxxx'
dimension="ga:productSku"
DIMS = ['ga:isoYearIsoWeek',dimension]
METRICS = ["ga:buyToDetailRate","ga:productDetailViews","ga:itemQuantity"]
requests_list = [
          {
            'viewId': VIEW_ID,
            'pageSize': 100000,
            'dateRanges': [
                {'startDate':'2022-12-05', 'endDate': '2023-03-05'}],
            'dimensions': [
                          {'name': name,
                          } for name in DIMS],
            'metrics': [{'expression': exp} for exp in METRICS],
     }]

data_v1 = ga_auth.reports().batchGet(body={'reportRequests':requests_list }).execute()
final=[data_v1]
  
token = data_v1["reports"][0]["nextPageToken"]
while token:
    requests_list = [
          {
            'viewId': VIEW_ID,
            'pageSize': 100000,
            "pageToken":token,
            'dateRanges': [
                {'startDate':'2022-12-05', 'endDate': '2023-03-05'}],
            'dimensions': [
                          {'name': name,
                          } for name in DIMS],
            'metrics': [{'expression': exp} for exp in METRICS],
      }]

    data = ga_auth.reports().batchGet(body={'reportRequests':requests_list }).execute()
    final.append(data)
    token=data["reports"][0]["nextPageToken"] if "nextPageToken" in list(data["reports"][0].keys()) else False
```

here is an example:

```
isoYearIsoWeek   productDetailViews
202249           15
202250           20
202251           30
202252           40
202301           50
202302           12
202303           0
202304           41     # ------ > where is 202305 ? on the site 202305's productDetailViews are 12
202306           74
202307           10
202308           4  
202309           15
```

I would like to all the weeks to come. I thought to fill the missing data with 0, but when I checked on the site, there was data greater than 0.